# std::move Not Working on RValue Reference Function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std, rvalue-reference

While trying to learn std::move and rvalue reference , i just came across the following:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vecNumbers;
    vecNumbers.push_back(10);
    vecNumbers.push_back(20);

    foo(std::move(vecNumbers));

    std::cout<<"After Move \n";
    std::cout<<"size:"<<vecNumbers.size()<<"\n";

    return 0;
}

void foo(  std::vector<int> &&value)
{
    std::cout<<"size in Function:"<<value.size()<<"\n";
}
```

The Output

```
size in Function:2
After Move
size:2
```

I was expecting the size to be 0 after calling **move** on **vector** but here it only moved as reference. Could someone please explain what is happening here.

Comment: Did you move (*stole* content of ) `value` inside `foo`? No, so why you assume that this vector should have size 0 ? `move` only cast to Rvalue ref.

Comment: As Scott Meyers likes to say: `std::move` does not move (and `std::forward` does not forward).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` only casts to Rvalue reference.

`foo` takes Rvalue ref to `vector<int>`. By `move(vecNumbers)` you get `vector<int>&&`. Inside `foo` you just access `vecNumbers` which is defined in `main`. You didn't do any action which changed the content of this vector.

If you really want to move (steal) content of `vecNumbers` you have to call either move constructor or move assignment operator. Inside `foo` you could do this in this way:

```
void foo(  std::vector<int>&& value)
{
    std::vector<int> v1{std::move(value)}; // invoke move ctor which steals content of value
    std::cout<<"size in Function:"<<value.size()<<"\n";
}
```

or you can change signature of foo to be:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> value) {

}
```

then when you call

```
foo(std::move(vecNumbers))
```

move constructor of `vector<T>` is called which moves `vecNumbers` to `value` inside `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption about [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is wrong:

> std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from",
>   i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another
>   object.
>
> In particular, std::move produces an xvalue expression that identifies
>   its argument t. **It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an
>   rvalue reference type.**

This doesn't mean the size of vector should become zero with your code.